# Difference between button and other views for visibility (android)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-xml

I have that xml with frame layout (with fragment in it):

```
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/main_fragment_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:elevation="20dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="visible">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/background_button"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#000"
                    android:backgroundTint="#000"
                    android:visibility="visible"/>

            </FrameLayout>
```

I don't want to use button there but if I change it to other View (View, ImageView, TextView...) it becomes invisible.

Comment: add this `android:visibility="visible"` to any view

Comment: I found that it will be visible if set elevation to 21dp, but I'm seriously don't know why.

Comment: That sounds off, but notice its parent is set to 20 elevation.  21 means it would be higher.  So that's what's happening.  As for why I have no idea, a child should be at the same elevation as its parent by default.

Comment: Bassem Abd Allah, of course, I have visibility attribute ="visible" like in the example

Comment: And the visibility isn't needed, visibility is visible by default.